# Android Map App not running on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-maps-v2, android-market-filtering

I have an issue to run Android Map V2 project on Eclipse.
Whenever I started Eclipse below error shown against my Map project.

> Dex Loader} Unable to execute dex: Java heap space.

And when I clean project it resolve but When I start my project so Eclipse hangs and after some time below error shown.

> Dex Loader} Unable to execute dex: Java heap space.
>
> Conversion to Devlik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space.

I don't know what to do? I searched alot and followed many ways but not solved this problem. :( How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the -XmsAm and -XmxBm parameters in eclipse.ini so that they are large enough. When you will see these parameters, the default will be -Xms40m and -Xmx384m. Increase the integer values to something like Xms512 and -Xmx512m and restart eclipse to see if this helps.

eclipse.ini is located at /etc/eclipse.ini in Ubuntu (assuming you installed Eclipse from the Ubuntu repositories).

Answer (score 0):

if you used correct google api key of your system and no problem by oter one than you used this now
Developer, I have met a Strange problem when I want use a third Party JAR, it remained Me that:    Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: null    Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: null    out of Memory Error ... An Internal Error occurred during: "Build Project."    Java heap space    This is the DEX Error, I Find the Solutions by Google, one way is to Modify the eclipse.ini, you CAN Increase the Memory allocated in eclipse.ini to this: -Xms128m-Xmx512m or something higher , but this Did not work for Me. After Modify the eclipse.ini, I Can not Start the Eclipse. By StackOverflow, I Find a Solution:    eclipse.ini file must have on-vm path on first line and second line. Do not try to put everything into one line!    -vm    C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.6.0_07 \ bin \ javaw.exe    After add the-vm and the path in My eclipse.ini, I CAN Start My Eclipse and the problem has been resolved.    Another way to Solve the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: null "problem is using the user Library, the Concrete steps are as follows:    1. Right-Click the Project in Eclipse and SELECT "Build Path -> Add Libraries ...."    2. Select from the List and User Library Click Next.    3. Click the "User Libraries ..." button.    4. Click "New ..." in the User Libraries dialog.    5. Give the user a name and SELECT the Library System Library CheckBox and Click OK.    6. Highlight the newly added in the user Library List and Click the "Add JARs ..." button and add the desired JAR Files.    7. Click OK on the User Libraries dialog.    8. Make sure the new user Library is checked in the Add Library dialog and ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways first is same as written above and the second one is you can change the heap space in the android map app itself as shown below.

android:largeHeap=["true" | "false"]

you can set this property to true in the manifest file.

Comment: where should i put this android:largeHeap=["true" | "false"] in manifest?